# Can we test BLE(Bluetooth Low Energy) example using andriod emulator?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to run and test the bluetooth low energy example. so is there any way so i can check the bluetooth related example using android emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry but it's **not possible**. It doesn't matter if it's normal Bluetooth or Low Energy. Android emulator does not have bluetooth capabilities. If you want to test your app, you have to do it on a real device.